# How to retain text-box values after postback

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I am calculating row total and grand total using jquery but my only issue is that i am losing the text-box values after postback.  Every text-box is reset to 0 when i click the AddNewRow button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
     $("[id*=txtDay1]").val("0");
     $("[id*=txtDay2]").val("0");

   });

   $("[id*=txtDay1]").live("keyup", function () {
     if (!jQuery.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
       if (!isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {
         var row = $(this).closest("tr");
         var number = parseFloat($("[id*=txtDay1]", row).val());
         $("[id*=lblTotal]", row).html(parseFloat($("[id*=txtDay2]", row).val()) + parseFloat($(this).val()));
       }
     } else {
       $(this).val('');
     }
     var grandTotal = 0;
     $("[id*=lblTotal]").each(function () {
       grandTotal = grandTotal + parseFloat($(this).html());
     });
     $("[id*=lblGrandTotal]").html(grandTotal.toString());
   });


   $("[id*=txtDay2]").live("keyup", function () {
     if (!jQuery.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
       if (!isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {
         var row = $(this).closest("tr");
         var number = parseFloat($("[id*=txtDay2]", row).val());
         $("[id*=lblTotal]", row).html(parseFloat($("[id*=txtDay1]", row).val())  + parseFloat($(this).val()));
       }
     } else {
       $(this).val('');
     }
     var grandTotal = 0;
     $("[id*=lblTotal]").each(function () {
       grandTotal = grandTotal + parseFloat($(this).html());
     });
     $("[id*=lblGrandTotal]").html(grandTotal.toString());
   });
    </script>
```

here is my gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv_Sub" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="gv_WeeklySub_RowDataBound" CssClass="table table-hover table-bordered table-responsive"

      GridLines="None" OnRowDeleting="gv_Sub_RowDeleting">
      <Columns>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Row ID" />


        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Day1">
          <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDay1" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
          </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle Width="40px" BackColor="#cccccc"/>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Day2">
          <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDay2" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
          </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
          <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server"
              Text="Add New Row" OnClick="ButtonAdd_Click" />
          </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
             <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
          <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblGrand" CssClass="text-primary" runat="server" Text="Grand Total:"></asp:Label>
          </FooterTemplate>
           <ItemStyle Width="40px" BackColor="#cccccc"/>
        </asp:TemplateField>   


          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Total">
          <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" CssClass="text-primary" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label>
          </ItemTemplate>
                 <%-- <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />--%>
          <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblGrandTotal" CssClass="text-primary" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:Label>
          </FooterTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
      </Columns>      
    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you're clearing it up. Just fix this code:

```
$(function () {
    if($("[id*=txtDay1]").val() == "")
        $("[id*=txtDay1]").val("0")

    if($("[id*=txtDay2]").val() == "")
        $("[id*=txtDay2]").val("0");

    //calculating grand total on postback
    calculateGrandTotal();
   });
```

You will need to re-calculate the `grandTotal` now, create a `function` for that and use it everywhere:

```
$("[id*=txtDay1]").live("keyup", function () {
 if (!jQuery.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
   if (!isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {
     var row = $(this).closest("tr");
     var number = parseFloat($("[id*=txtDay1]", row).val());
     $("[id*=lblTotal]", row).html(parseFloat($("[id*=txtDay2]", row).val()) + parseFloat($(this).val()));
   }
 } else {
   $(this).val('');
 }

 //calculate grand total
 calculateGrandTotal();

 //remove this
 /*var grandTotal = 0;
 $("[id*=lblTotal]").each(function () {
   grandTotal = grandTotal + parseFloat($(this).html());
 });
 $("[id*=lblGrandTotal]").html(grandTotal.toString());*/
});


$("[id*=txtDay2]").live("keyup", function () {
 if (!jQuery.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
   if (!isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {
     var row = $(this).closest("tr");
     var number = parseFloat($("[id*=txtDay2]", row).val());
     $("[id*=lblTotal]", row).html(parseFloat($("[id*=txtDay1]", row).val())  + parseFloat($(this).val()));
   }
 } else {
   $(this).val('');
 }

 //calculate grand total
 calculateGrandTotal();

 //remove this
 /*var grandTotal = 0;
 $("[id*=lblTotal]").each(function () {
   grandTotal = grandTotal + parseFloat($(this).html());
 });
 $("[id*=lblGrandTotal]").html(grandTotal.toString());*/
});

function calculateGrandTotal(){
    var grandTotal = 0;
    $("[id*=lblTotal]").each(function () {
        grandTotal = grandTotal + parseFloat($(this).html());
    });
    $("[id*=lblGrandTotal]").html(grandTotal.toString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shaharyar, that fixed the postback issue but i have problem now when i click the add new row button the GrandTotal label shows NaN or 0.  How can i recalculate the GrandTotal after postback?  thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You need to use IsPostBack method, since you are using JS, write this in your c# code behind.

```
if(IsPostBack)
{
   ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "IsPostBack", "var isPostBack = true;", true);
}
```

Then wrap your JS calculations with this method and output the value the textbox

```
if(!isPostBack) {
   //display your value in the textbox
}
```